# Wrong number of items passed 12, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy agregando una columna a un df que he creado usando `data_range()`, para después usarla como index del df pero me genera un ValueError.

```
sensor_dates= pd.date_range(start='01/01/2018 00:00:00',end='01/01/2018 00:29:10', periods=1751)
sensor_dates

sensor['sensor_dates']=sensor
sensor.index(sensor.sensor_dates,freq='infer')
sensor.head()
```

El error dice:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    122 
    123         if self._validate_ndim and self.ndim and len(self.mgr_locs) != len(self.values):
--> 124             raise ValueError(
    125                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
    126                 f"placement implies {len(self.mgr_locs)}"

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 12, placement implies 1
```

Comment: ¿Cómo está definida la variable `sensor` al comenzar el código?

Comment: sensor = pd.read_csv('../sub_1.csv'),es un dataframe

Comment: No se panda. ¿qué significa esto `sensor['sensor_dates']=sensor`? Parece una asignación recursiva.

Comment: Intente ejecutar tu código, pero me dio error en la primera línea. El error es `ValueError: Of the three parameters: start, end, and periods, exactly two must be specified`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sensor['sensor_dates']=sensor
```

En la columna sensor_dates estas guardando el df completo (que deduzco tiene 12 columnas).
Prueba sensor['sensor_dates']=**sensor_dates**

```
sensor_dates= pd.date_range(start='01/01/2018 00:00:00',end='01/01/2018 00:29:10', periods=1751)
sensor['sensor_dates']=sensor_dates
#sensor.index(sensor_dates) # NO
sensor.head()
```

Para usarla como índice

```
sensor.set_index(sensor_dates)
```

Con esto, aparece como índice **y como columna**. Si quieres borrar la columna:

```
sensor.drop(['sensor_dates'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```